# The graph, filter query by relationship non id value

Tags: query

I have these types:

```
    type Poll @entity {
        id: ID!
        hash: String!
        contributions: [Contribution!]! @derivedFrom(field: "poll")
    }

    type Contribution @entity {
        id: ID!
        contributorAddress: Bytes!
        poll: Poll!
    }
```

I need to query a poll filtered by the contribution contributorAddress but it seems that I'm only able to do it with the contribution ID.

Here are the mappings:

```
    poll.contributions = new Array<string>(0)

    let contributions = poll.contributions
    contributions.push(contribution.id)
    poll.contributions = contributions
```

Thanks